# java command classpath issue

Tags: java, jar, javac

I am having strange issue in this simple scenario.

I am having a jar file which contains following class:

```
package com.example;

public class Test{
    public void perform(){
       System.out.println("Performing testing one");
    }
}
```

And I have created a Main class to call the perform method as followed:

```
import com.example.Test;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     Test test=new Test();
     test.perform();
    }
}
```

I have put both the jar and Main.java file in same folder and successfully compiled the Main.java file using following command:

> javac -cp ".\*" Main.java

But when I am trying to run the Main class using following command:

> java -cp ".\*" Main

It gives following error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class Main

If I try to run Main class without `-cp` argument it gives following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/example/Test
>           at Main.main(Main.java:5) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.Test
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           ... 1 more

The syntax is correct then what I am doing wrong here...?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After a lot of experiment and searches on net, I have finally found that we need to put `;` after classpath to make it work.
So following command does run the Main class:

> java -cp ".\*"; Main

Comment: That doesn't make it work, and it isn't necessary. It can't work unless you specify the class to run correctly, and you haven't.

Comment: @EJP Can you please explain why `java -cp ".\*"; Main` works and `java -cp ".\*" Main` doesn't?

Comment: Neither works. Cannot reproduce. You will get what I did: the same `NoClassDefFoundError` you mentioned in your post, unless you've changed your code.

Comment: @EJP I have checked the posted code and the behavior does occur. I am using Java  1.8.0_73.

Comment: @RohitGupta, Wow thanks buddy. i got my solution. i have tried to resolved for two days. you saved my time. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

When using -cp you need to specify jar names one by one. Using * does not usually add anything to the classpath. Good luck!

Comment: i have also tried to run java command as followed `java -cp "test1.jar" Main` but still same error

Comment: What about the jar where Test sits on, you appear to only have compiled main.java. Also, the jars need to be on local dir to be used this way, otherwise you need full path.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is wrong.

- The source code should be in a directory called `com/example`.
- You should be in the directory containing `com`.
- The compiler command is

  ```
  javac com/example/Main.java
  ```
- The execute command is

  ```
  java com.example.Main
  ```

You don't need a JAR file with only one class in it.